# How to print single asterisk in R Markdown table using 'kable'?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I created a **table** in an **R Markdown** document which I want to print in **html format** using `kable` and `kable_styling` from the `kableExtra` package. One column contains cells that should only show one single asterisk "*".

In the html, these cells are depicted as points / bulletpoints?! How can I change my output in a way that the single asterisks are just printed as asterisks (like the cells containing "**" or "***")?

Example Code:

````
```{r example}
df <- data.frame(type = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 number = runif(4),
                 asterisks = c("*", "*", "**", "***"))
df %>% 
  kable(caption = "Single asterisk looks like point...") %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = F, position = "left")
```
````

html output:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You use the backslash you can escape the asterisk. Not sure if you want a double or single. `df <- data.frame(type = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),number = runif(4),asterisks = c("\\*", "\*", "**", "***"))`

Comment: The double backslash worked, thank you!! I had only tried the single one before... :D